# Visual Studio keeps replacing my custom control namespace in designer.cs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-customcontrol

I try to create a custom control which inherits from GridView ( using tut http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f(v=vs.100).aspx ). After each build Visual Studio keeps replacing my reference to my custom namespace with its own in Default.aspx.designer.cs

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.GridViewCustom GridView1;
```

each time I did put

```
protected GridViewCustom.GridViewCustom GridView1;
```

Why ?

In assembly.cs I have added

```
using System.Web.UI;
...
[assembly: TagPrefix("GridViewCustom", "GridViewCustom")]
```

In default.aspx I have:

```
    <asp:GridViewCustom ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridViewCustom>
```

This is my source code for the control (source file is in App_Code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridViewCustom
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:GridViewCustom runat=server></{0}:GridViewCustom>")]
    public class GridViewCustom : System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem; came across this similar question, but haven't tried its solution yet:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498506/visual-studio-2010-keeps-changing-my-winforms-control

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  [One option](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/532249-wap-vs2005-keeps-changing-my-user-control-types) is suggested by the autogenerated designer file -- remove the declaration from the `.designer.cs` file and explicitly declare it in your codebehind file.

Otherwise, you might try looking into the solution outlined in this question: [Visual Studio 2010 keeps changing my winforms control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498506/visual-studio-2010-keeps-changing-my-winforms-control).

**Update:**
Having [registered my controls globally in a `web.config` file](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx), I just experimented with changing the `tagPrefix` declaration to something unique, as opposed to an existing prefix shared by other custom controls, and suddenly everything is fine.  The strange thing is that I no longer see the declaration in the designer file, but it still works.

Still confusing.